# Django + Heroku: Out of Memory problems

Tags: python, django, heroku

So this is my first time deploying a django instance on Heroku. My site has had 1000 visits so far and 600 unique visits. We get about 60-200 visits per day. The link is https://socialspark.spuro.org/

Today, 6 days into being live - our site is running into a lot of memory issues. I.E., cannot allocate dyno process or, cannot allocate memory:

```
OperationalError at /
FATAL:  out of memory
DETAIL:  Failed on request of size 33208.
could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory

FATAL:  out of memory
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Is this really because Django get scale this information? Am I doing something wrong in my code? It's really difficult to diagnose.

I've even updated our process to 2X (and thus paying) but I'm still encountering

```
could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an error on Heroku's part for their starter DBs.

For others that experience this, look out for similar threads on Stack Overflow - which had also affirmed that this may have been an issue with Heroku. In debugging this, I was instead encouraged to review DB optimization, among other things. Following this, I optimized all of my queries and I still ran into this error.

Just look out for similar threads like this one, send a ticket and then examine your own code. You could save yourself a few hours.

Comment: (I haven't yet tried to duplicate your fix, but) I see that their "Basic" Postgres plan also has no RAM, so I wonder if it suffers from the same problem. What Postgres plan did you upgrade to?

Comment: I never ended up upgrading Postgres and, after submitting my ticket, have not encountered the issue for the second time.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting server helped in my case (maintenance mode on and off)